# Как сделать, чтобы анимация не останавливалась

Tags: java, android

Есть такая анимация:

```
android:duration="100"
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fromXScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="1.0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:startOffset="0"
android:toXScale="0.9"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toYScale="0.9" />
```

Как работает: объект сначала уменьшается,а потом возвращается в исходное состояние. (объект-ImageView)

В коде обращаюсь так:

```
anim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.clickbutton);
```

и вызываю так:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           v.startAnimation(anim);
 switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
    {
           stopPlayerIfNeeded();
          playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);
                        }
      break;
```

Все работает как часы, но хотелось бы, чтобы после нажатия анимация "постоянно работала" т.е нажал я на `case R.id.b1` - выполнилось действие, но анимация продолжала работать до того момента, пока не выбрал другой `R.id.*` и т.к далее

/////////////////////////////////////////
как в этом случае остановить анимацию?сейчас так: 
выбрал R.id.b1: все запустилось и работает, выбрал R.id.b2: запустилась анимация но и на R.id.b1: продолжает выполняться анимация,а нужно остановить

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr_imageB.length; j++) {
arr_imageB[j].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

v.startAnimation(anim);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.b1:
    {

            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
            playSample(soundsRawResIds[0]);

         }

    break;
case R.id.b2:

{
            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
            playSample(soundsRawResIds[1]);

        }

    break;
case R.id.b3:
{
            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
            playSample(soundsRawResIds[2]);

        }

    break;
case R.id.b4:
{
            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
            playSample(soundsRawResIds[3]);
         }

    break;
case R.id.b5: {
    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
    playSample(soundsRawResIds[4]);
}
    break;
case R.id.b6: {
    stopPlayerIfNeeded();
    playSample(soundsRawResIds[5]);

}

    break;
case R.id.b7:
{
            stopPlayerIfNeeded();
            playSample(soundsRawResIds[6]);

        }
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если анимация лежит в `<set>` то атрибут `android:repeatCount="infinite"` должен работать

Comment: подскажите,сейчас так получается,что все отлично работает в плане анимации,но если я выбрал case R.id.b1: а потом case R.id.b2 то анимация воспроизвод. у обоих элементов,я так понимаю,что мне нужно делать проверку и останавливать анимацию?

Comment: Да, анимацию в вьюшки можно отрубить с помощью view.clearAnimation();

Comment: т.е я у каждого  R.id.b прописываю view.clearAnimation(); ?

Comment: Вам надо написать метод, в котором бы на всех вьюшках вырубали анимацию при нажатию на кнопку и запускали на нужной

Comment: @ Андроид Андроид
а потом вызывать метод в кесах?

Comment: Получается так=)

Comment: @ Андроид Андроид
не представляю как)буду думать

Answer (score 3):

Повесьте слушатель окончания анимации и в нём ещё раз её проиграйте, снова повесив слушатель:

```
View viewToAnimate = ...;
final int animResId = R.anim.anim_file;

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, animResId);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
    {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, animResId);
        anim.setAnimationListener(this);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0)
    {
    }
});

viewToAnimate.startAnimation(anim);
```

Так она будет повторяться ~бесконечно.

Comment: Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0)
            {
                anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.clickbutton);
                anim.setAnimationListener(this);
                rootViewB.startAnimation(anim);
            }

а как тогда вызывать данный метод и останавливать анимацию,т.е  R.id.b1: я нажал, запустилась анимация,все ок, нажал R.id.b2: мне же b1 нужно остановить,т.е сделать проверку,не омгу понять как  в вашем варианте это сделать

Comment: @upward, попробуйте как-то так:http://stackoverflow.com/a/30501784/3212712

Comment: добавил в шапку код
я понимаю,что нужно вызывать clearAnimation(),только как в мое случае...все перепробовал

Comment: @upward, ну... Типа пробежаться также по массиву вьюх и над каждой вызвать метод остановки...

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб
обновил в шапке инфу про анимацию

Comment: @upward, не стоит бесконечно править вопрос с уже принятым ответом. Тем более, что у вас уже другой вопрос - не как зациклить анимацию, а как остановить. Задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Бесконечная анимация

```
anim.setRepeatCount(-1);
```

Остановка анимации

```
v.getAnimation().setRepeatCount(0);
```